# Parenting: possible to parent only Location? (not rotation)

Tags: camera, parent

I made camera set parent to object.
When the camera rotates, the object rotates together.
I want the object only follow the location, not the rotation of the camera.
Is this possible with parenting?

[image]

[image]
wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK this cannot be done with parenting. But...

you could simply use the copy location constraint instead. It just copies the location of another object.

[image]

result:

[image]